# Camel SoapJaxbDataFormat with multiple namespace(s)

Tags: soap, namespaces, jaxb, apache-camel, dataformat

i have a need to marshal inbound xml into a SOAP data format within my Camel route for use in data transformation, i have encounters an issue where the inbound message contains a namespace defined in an element other then root which leads to parts of the message being lost or incorrectly formatted.

How would i go about defining a SoapJaxbDataFormat for my message with multiple namespaces?

**Example Camel Route i have been using to track down my issues**

```
import com.example.ws.ExampleDataResponse;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.soap.name.QNameStrategy;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.SoapJaxbDataFormat;

public class ExampleCamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

   // defining my SOAP format
   SoapJaxbDataFormat soapExampleDataResponse;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    // Setting my data format
    soapExampleDataResponse = new SoapJaxbDataFormat(ExampleDataResponse.class.getPackage().getName(), new QNameStrategy(new QName("http://ws.example.com","exampleDataResponse")));

    // Enter route definition here
      from("amqp:queue:{{ExampleDataResponse.queue}}").routeId("ExampleDataResponse")
                .streamCaching()
                .log("Data receved from example")
                // view the orignal message
                .to("file:C:/Camel_Target?fileName=ExampleData_Orignal.xml", "direct:writeMarshaledData", "direct:writeUnMarshaledData");

      from("direct:writeMarshaledExampleData").routeId("writeMarshaledExampleData")
                .marshal(soapExampleDataResponse)
                // view the marshaled message
                .to("file:C:/Camel_Target?fileName=ExampleData_marshal.xml");

      from("direct:writeUnMarshaledExampleData").routeId("writeUnMarshaledExampleData")
                .unmarshal(soapExampleDataResponse)
                // view the unmarshaled message
                .to("file:C:/Camel_Target?fileName=ExampleData_UnMarshaled.xml");          
}



}
```

**Example of the original inbound xml message written out to file, i will need to marshal / unmarshal this data to a SOAP format**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <exampleDataResponse xmlns="http://ws.example.com">
            <exampleDataReturn>
                <name>user1</name>
                <number>8797877979877</number>
                <contacts>
                    <ns1:name xmlns:ns1="http://contact.ws.example.com">contact1</ns1:name>
                    <ns2:number xmlns:ns2="http://contact.ws.example.com">4545664464564</ns2:number>
                </contacts>
            </exampleDataReturn>
        </exampleDataResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Example marshaled data written out to file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:Envelope xmlns:ns5="http://data.contact.ws.example.com" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns4="http://contact.ws.example.com" xmlns:ns3="http://ws.example.com">
    <ns2:Body>
        <ns3:exampleDataResponse>4545664464564</ns3:exampleDataResponse>
    </ns2:Body>
</ns2:Envelope>
```

As you can see the data here is incorrect.

**Example of unmarshaled message written out to file**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:exampleDataResponse xmlns="http://contact.ws.example.com" xmlns:ns2="http://ws.example.com"/>
```

As you can see the data here is incorrect, i use SoapJaxbDataFormat's alot in my camel routes and have not encounters this issue before, stranger still the route doesn't error.

Thank you in advanced for any help in how i can properly define this format.

Comment: Have you tried with the "multiple context" configuration? See: http://camel.apache.org/jaxb.html at "Using Spring XML"